# Sorting date based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an expiration date column on my table, I want to fetch records in order that are nearly to expire. I used 'ORDER BY DATE DESC' but it only arranges the date in descending order.

Output using 'ORDER BY DATE'

```
2016-10-31
2016-10-06
2016-03-10
```

desired output:

```
2016-10-06
2016-10-31
2016-03-10
```

Comment: What is the logic for desired output?

Comment: He wants the data to be sorted in descending order of months and ascending order of days with in each month.

Comment: fetch records that is near on the date today.

Comment: Can you be more specific....

Comment: as what you have mentioned @Teja. "sorted in descending order of months and ascending order of days with in each month" this is the logic of the output

Comment: Doesnt my answer help u in solving the question?

Comment: already did. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As disturbingly brilliant as Gordon is, I think there was an oversight.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Date date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-10-14'),           -- Added 10/14 +4 Days
('2016-10-31'),
('2016-10-06'),
('2016-03-10')

Select *, NDays=datediff(day, getdate(), [date]) 
From @YourTable
Order By abs(datediff(day, getdate(), [date]))
```

Returns

```
Date        NDays
2016-10-14  4          << Record Added (Should be below 10/6)
2016-10-06  -4
2016-10-31  21
2016-03-10  -214
```

I think the safest (and far less elegant) would be something more like this

```
Select *, NDays=datediff(day, getdate(), [date]) 
From @YourTable
Order By Year(Date) Desc,Month(Date) Desc,Day(Date)
```

Returns

```
Date        NDays
2016-10-06  -4
2016-10-14  4
2016-10-31  21
2016-03-10  -214
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
 order by abs(datediff(day, getdate(), [date]))
```

Comment: by the way sir, what is abs?

Comment: @MDP - `ABS` converts all the values to positive values. Here is a official documentation link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in the below SQL.

```
1) First sort by date in descending order
2) With in each month sort the dates in ascending order of day.
```

( The below DATEPART function will calculate the DAY from DATE. )

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DATA
ORDER BY DATEPART( MONTH, date ) DESC, DATEPART( DAY, date );
```

Comment: alias in `order by`? and btw, sql server doesn't have `extract` function.

Comment: it doesn't work. same output using order by date desc.

Comment: Try now.. I am extracting month and sorting in desc order then sorting data in ascending order of day